# IndexOutOfBounds error when trying to get last value

Tags: java, arrays

So I am suppose to loop through the array and finding at what points the array starts a new year and how many days in that year. The problem I have is I can't get the last year of the array which is 2013.

2010 [25202, 25567) 365 days.

2011 [25567, 25932) 365 days.

2012 [25932, 26298) 366 days.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26663
at WeatherAnalysis.yearsArray(WeatherAnalysis.java:213)


    public static void yearsArray(String a[]) { // Array to find the amnount of days in a year
        int range1 = 0;
        int range2 = 1;
        String year = "";


        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length-1; i++) {

            String s = a[i];
            String p = a[i+1];



            if (s.equals(p)) {
                range2 ++;

            }else{


                year = s;
                System.out.println(year+" ["+range1+", "+range2 +") "+ (range2-range1)+" days");
                range1 = range2;
                range2 ++;
            }



        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your loop goes up to `a.length-1`. This is the last index in the array. However, you try to access the index after this when you say `String p = a[i+1]`. This is trying to access `i+1`, which is outside the bounds of the array.

Here's a debugging tip: when the exception says `at WeatherAnalysis.yearsArray(WeatherAnalysis.java:213)`, that `213` is the line number where the exception is being thrown from. This is probably the line with `String p = a[i+1]` on it.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's out of the array but I am having trouble getting it to work how I need it to. because it compares the first index to the second to see if it changes year. When it does it prints out the year, index range, and days in a year...I don't know how to get it to finish 2013 without going out of array bounds

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. Can you just end the loop one iteration earlier?

Comment: @C-Webz
@Greg Greg is right. I suppose If you change the loop to `for (int i = 0; i<a.length-1; i++) ` you are OK

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you refer to `a[i + 1]`.  When `i` is at the last index of the array, `i + 1` is after the end of the array, causing Java to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.